# React using refs instead of #id selector

Tags: css, reactjs, css-selectors, jsx, use-ref

I have come across a few different articles saying refs are the 'react way' of doing things in place of the #id selector. I'm not certain why. What is the explanation for using refs instead of #id?

```
import {useRef} from 'react';

function Home() {
  const exampleRef = useRef(null)

  return (
    <div ref={exampleRef}> Hello world </div>
  )
}

export default Home;
```

vs.

```
function Home() {
  return (
    <div id='example'> Hello world </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two main reasons:

1. You can skip the `Document.getElementById()` call and directly access `exampleRef.current`
2. The `current` property of the `useRef` object is fully mutable and can be assigned any arbitrary value. Mutating it does not trigger full component re-renders (like calling the setter function from a `useState` hook would), which is sometimes necessary for performance.

Sometimes w3schools articles are lacking in substance, but [their `useRef` article](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_useref.asp) has some good examples of simple use cases.

Answer (score 0):

React `useRef` returns a object which remains same reference between re-renders with a `current` property which is mutable.

The reason `ref` is preferred than `getElementById` is that

- It is easy to access , no need to define an id to your DOM node just for accessing it.
- Unlike `ids` refs are unique, you don't need to worry about it while declaring it. if you have more than one DOM node with same `id` in the document, `getElementById` might not return the element you expect.

You can read more about refs in [React's beta docs](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/manipulating-the-dom-with-refs)